# Java: Creating an object and adding straight into ArrayList - two ways

Tags: java, oop, object

Having some trouble with some basic concepts of creating objects. In the code below I am creating a [person] object and then adding it to the [persons] arraylist. It works fine.

```
ArrayList<Person> persons = new ArrayList<>();
Person person = new Person(name, age);
persons.add(person);
```

However if I try to do something like:

```
persons.add(Person person = new Person(name, age));
```

It doesn't work for some reason.

On the other hand, if I do this:

```
        persons.add(new Person(name, age));
```

It works!
I'm thinking there is something wrong with doing the Person person initial part in my wrong attempt, probably to do with declaring objects but I'm not too sure what the reason for not including it in would be?

Comment: The code `Person person = new Person(name, age)` doesn't return anything and add() expects an argument. The statement `new Person(name, age)` returns an object of type Person on the other hand

Answer (score 2):

```
Person person = new Person(name, age);
```

is a statement (it's not something you can use as an expression, it doesn't return any value), while

```
person = new Person(name, age)
```

is an expression statement, which can be used for both assigning and returning a value

```
persons.add(person = new Person(name, age));
```

To read:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se13/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.5